# Converting object with AM/PM to datetime in hours round down

Tags: pandas, dataframe, datetime

I have a dataframe with 1 column with object type.

Time

---

4:11:45 PM
4:12:17 PM

I want to convert this to datetime in hours only. 
I have tried the following but some error message below

```
test = pd.to_datetime(df3.Time,format = '%H:%M:%S').df.hour
```

```
ValueError: time data '4:11:45 PM' does not match format %H:%M:%S (match)
```

I thought of removing the PM, but then if I remove it, the conversion will lose the AM and PM meaning. Is it something I left out before I use the datetime conversion? Or my syntax is wrong?

Most solutions I read from stackoverflow is non-pandas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change format for `%I:%M:%S %` for `%I` is datetime in 12-hour format and `%p` is locale's equivalent of either AM or PM. Check more info in [`https://strftime.org`](https://strftime.org/).

Last change `df.hour` to `dt.hour` (typo):

```
test = pd.to_datetime(df3.Time,format = '%I:%M:%S %p').dt.hour
print (test)
0    16
1    16
Name: Time, dtype: int64
```